# Why ever purchase a wildcard SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I was looking at wildcard SSL certs recently, and the lowest price on Namecheap is $94/year. Now, a regular single domain SSL cert from them starts at $9/year. My question is this: why wouldn't I just pay, for example, $27/year for a domain and two subdomains, rather than a whopping $94/year? The only thing I can think of is that with the wildcard cert, you skip the hassle of reissuing each individual domain cert.

Any other reasons I'm missing?

Comment: Lets say you wanted to https enable [stackexchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).  Notice how there are over 100 subdomains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the scenario where someone may require more than 9 domains/subdomains.

Also, it is common to require a unique IP address per SSL certificate.  While SNI (the protocol that allows multiple certificates to be issued from a single IP) is supported in most web servers, it is not always available.

If it is not available, then you have to host each subdomain at a unique IP address.  As IP addresses are often at a premium, a wildcard cert may be a better option.

Comment: Right, I understand that. But in my situation, for just a domain and two subdomains, it makes more sense to buy three individual certificates, correct?

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack If you have the IP addresses or SNI, and are happy with the admin, then it would be cheaper to get three.